# Proof that $x^d\equiv d \pmod p$ has either no solutions or exactly $d$ solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-arithmetic

**Prop.** p prime, $d\in\mathbb Z^+$, $d | p-1$. Then for any particular $c\not\equiv0 \pmod{p}$, the congruence

$$
x^d \equiv c \pmod{p}
$$

has either **no solutions or exactly d solutions**.

******Proof.******

Consider the map $f:\{1,2,...,p-1\}\rightarrow \{1,2,...,p-1\}$, $x\mapsto x^d \pmod p$.

Suppose $x^d\equiv c \pmod c$ had at least one solution. Then consider some image $c$. Denote

$e=\frac{p-1}{d}.$  Raise both sides of the congruence to $e$:

$c^e\equiv (x^d)^e\equiv x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$  by FLT. Thus, any such $c$ is a solution to the conrguence $x^e\equiv 1 \pmod p$. By the analogy to the Fundamental theorem of alegbra in modular arithmetic, this has $≤e$ solutions, meaning that we have at most $e$ elements $c$ in the image of $f.$

Now fix a particular $c$, say $c_j$. The number of preimages. of $c_j$ is the number of solutions to $x^d\equiv 1 \pmod p$. In particular, each $c_j$ has  $≤d$ preimages. Then the number of elements in the range of $f$ is $≤ed=p-1$. However, there are exactly $p-1$ elements in the range of $f$, meaning all inequalities in the proof are in fact equalities. $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\square$

---

Can someone please help explain this proof? After working my way through, I seem to be unable to grasp the "big picture" plan/motivations behind certain steps in this proof. In particular, why do we need to establish that "each $c_j$ has  $≤d$ preimages", and why does this imply that "the number of elements in the range of $f$ is $≤ed=p-1$". This seems like a combinatorial argument here, but I am struggling to see how.

Most confusing to me is this very last statement: "meaning all inequalities in the proof are in fact equalities."

I would also appreciate any intuitive explanations or alternative simpler proofs.

Comment: Are there quite some typos? Should the question RHS be $c$ or $d$? In the proof, that $x^d\equiv c\pmod c$ can be written as $x^d\equiv 0\pmod c$, but is that relevant? Does the proof intend to consider the domain of $f$, not the range of $f$?

Comment: Perhaps so, which may be why I am confused. This proof was originally handwritten quite messly; I transcribed it into TeX.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is the following lemma.

**Lemma 1** Assume an algebraically closed field $F$ with $\operatorname{char} F = p$. If $gcd(d,p)=1$, then there are exactly $\phi(d)$ $d$-primitive roots of unity.

At least, it is well-known that $(p-1)$-primitive roots of unity exist in $Z_p$, so do $d$-primitive roots of unity. Suppose $w \in Z_p^*$ is a $d$-primitive roots of unity. Then $x^d = c$ implies $(xw^i)^{d}=c$, $1\leq i < d$.

For $1\leq i < j < d$, $xw^i \not= xw^j$ since $w^{j-i} \not= 1$. Also $X^d=c$ will not have more than $d$ roots in a field.

Comment: I recommend drawing pictures in the complex field $C$ to see the relations between $x^d=c$ and $x^d=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also add that I would prefer non Abstract Algebra arguments at the undergraduate level; only elementary number theory and/or combinatorial explanations as I have not taken an Abstract Algebra course yet.

Comment: The existence of $(p-1)$-primitive roots in $Z_p$ is a famous result of elementary number theory.

Answer (score 1):

The last point is as follows:  You have no more than $e$ buckets.  Each bucket contains no more than $d$ preimages.  Together, all of the buckets contain all $p-1$ nonzero elements of $\Bbb Z/ p \Bbb Z$, with none omitted.  Since $ed=p-1$, the only way for this to work is if you in fact have all $e$ buckets and if every one of those buckets has all $d$ permissible preimages; otherwise (in other words, if any of the inequalities were strict), you would necessarily omit some element.

You need to know that no bucket contains more than $d$ preimages for this line of reasoning to work.

Comment: My main confusion is why you’re multiplying the number of preimages by the number of images $e$ and $d$. From my current understanding, our overall goal is to show that the number of preimages $x$ is $d$ right?